# Error of Cannot cast LinearLayout to ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a new application and it works fine this afternoon, and I don't know why(probably import android-support v7?)

I have the folloiwng logs when I start my activity

```
10-01 08:09:16.690: I/dalvikvm-heap(2115): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.026MB for 2536932-byte allocation
10-01 08:09:17.180: W/dalvikvm(2115): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d1ab20)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115): Process: com.example.jizhang, PID: 2115
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jizhang/com.jaskey.jizhang.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at com.jaskey.jizhang.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-01 08:09:17.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2115):     ... 11 more
```

And the exception is thrown at :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//here where the error is thrown
        mPageAdpater=new MainPageAdpater(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPageAdpater);
```

My layout is defined like:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is that?!

Comment: have you cleaned up the project before posting ?

Comment: clean the project , Remove the `android-support-v4.jar` from your project, copy the jar file from `yourdrive:\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4`, add this library to your project, restart eclipse.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse generally solves "unable to cast x to y" errors.

Comment: just clean and rebuild your project. please.

Comment: @lmitiyaz I tried cleannig. And then it says every thing with R.java compiles erorr. I found that I change the package of the R.java before(from com.example to com.jaskey), After I clean, I found that the the R is becomming com.example again, and I change the import into com.example, and now it works. Can't I change the package of R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning your project

In eclipse 
Project->Clean->Clean Projects Selected Below
and select your project and press OK

Comment: Thank you! I tried. And then it says every thing with R.java compiles erorr. I found that I change the package of the R.java before(from com.example to com.jaskey), After I clean, I found that the the R is becomming com.example again, and I change the import into com.example,  and now it works. Can't I change the package of R?

Comment: Try to change package name in manifest,



<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.facebook.test"

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >